# Is it possible to force particular registers in inline assembly code?

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

I have the following assembly code:

```
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
  "1: subi %0, 1"        "\n\t"
  "brne 1b"
  : "=d" (__count)
  : "M" (__count));
```

which results in the following compiler ouptut

```
  ce:   81 50           subi    r24, 0x01   ; 1
  d0:   f1 f7           brne    .-4         ; 0xce <main>
  d2:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
  d4:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
```

How can i achieve the following:

```
  ce:   81 50           subi    r16, 0x01   ; 1
  d0:   f1 f7           brne    .-4         ; 0xce <main>
  d2:   80 e0           ldi r16, 0x00   ; 0
```

Is it even possible to tell the compiler to use r16 instead of r24:r25? That way i can reduce the cycle count by 1 which is used by the ldi r25,0x00 line.

Thanks
Jack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is old and you most certainly already solved it, but for archiving purposes, let me answer it: yes, you can. Declare `__count` like this:

```
register <type> __count __asm__ ("r16");
```

And voilá!  Using the GNU extension [explicit register variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html#Explicit-Reg-Vars), you've declared that the C variable `__count` should always be placed in r16 wherever it is used - including outside of an ASM call.

Note that this declaration should have local scope, otherwise the compiler will avoid using this register in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html#io_ops

It seems you can't force it to use a specific register. However, if you use `"=a"` instead of `"=d"` you would restrict it to registers r16..r23 which should be what you want (because you just don't want it to use the 'paired' registers r24/r25)